How to write a function for the normal copula in R?
How can I write the following function for the normal copula in R?
$$
C_\theta(u, v)=\Phi_\theta\left(\Phi^{-1}(u), \Phi^{-1}(v)\right),
$$
where $\Phi$ is the $N(0,1)$ cdf, $\Phi^{-1}$ is the functional inverse of $\Phi$ and $\Phi_\theta$ is the bivariate standard normal CDF with correlation $\theta$.
I have tried writing it like this but it is not good because eventually when I try to find the log likelihood it does not return any value.
pcopula.fam1 <- function(u, v, a) {
  return(exp(-(qnorm(u)^2-2*a*qnorm(u)*qnorm(y)+qnorm(y)^2)/(2*(1-a^2)))/(2*pi))
}

The Frank copula
This is how I was able to write my function for the Frank copula, but I am stuck with the normal copula described above.
pcopula.fam1<-function(u,v,a){
  - (1/a) * log(1 + ((exp(-a*u)-1) * (exp(-a*v)-1))/(exp(-a)-1))
} 


I voted to reopen this question because it implicitly asks for a computable formula for the bivariate Normal CDF.

By definition, the bivariate CDF for variables $(X,Y)$ is
$$\Phi_\theta(x,y) = \Pr(X\le x,\ Y\le y).$$
It is the area of an infinite rectangle (with upper right vertex at $(x,y)$) weighted by the probability density.  Fubini's Theorem states it can be computed as an iterated integral.  For a bivariate Normal distribution, one integral will result in an error function; the second integral usually is best computed numerically.  (The special case where one of the upper limits is infinite, solved at How can I calculate $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right)\phi(w)\,\mathrm dw$, hints at the difficulty.)
Several well-established R packages offer this capability.  The following solution copula.normal uses pmvnorm in the mvtnorm package to compute $\Phi_\theta.$  The inverses $\Phi^{-1}$ of the standard univariate Normal are offered in any statistical computing platform: in R they are called qnorm.
copula.normal <- Vectorize(function(u, v, rho = 0) {
  require(mvtnorm)
  pmvnorm(upper = qnorm(c(u, v)), corr = matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), 2))
})

You can see this is a direct translation of the mathematical formula into the corresponding function calls.
To illustrate its use, let's plot some of these CDFs.
u <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 21)
pars <- par()
par(mfrow = c(2, 2), mai = c(0.5,0.4,1,0.2))
for (rho in c(-0.8, 0, 0.5, 0.9)) 
  image(outer(u, u, copula.normal, rho = rho), 
        main = bquote(rho==.(rho)), cex.main = 2)
u <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 201);
pars <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2), mai = c(0.5,0.4,1,0.2));
for (rho in c(-0.8, 0, 0.5, 0.9)) 
  image(outer(u, u, copula.normal, rho = rho), 
        main = bquote(rho==.(rho)), cex.main = 2)
par(pars)


This looks about right, because as $\rho\to-1$ (perfect negative correlation) the plot should look like the lower Fréchet–Hoeffding bound $W$, which it approximates for $\rho=-0.8$ in the upper left, and as $\rho\to1$ (perfect positive correlation) the plot should look like the upper Fréchet–Hoeffding bound $M$], which it approximates for $\rho=0.9$ in the lower right, passing through the independence copula $C(u,v)=uv$ for $\rho=0$ (upper right) whose level curves are perfect hyperbolae.
Because this example computes $4\times 201\times 201 = 161,604$ of these integrals, it takes a few seconds.  In practice, if you need many such calculations, you can speed it up by precomputing values on a coarse grid and interpolating.

I will apologize in advance for this comment if it's not the correct way to go, but I thought it needs bringing to a moderator attention, since the question and answer by the OP are actually from different accounts:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/412591/aria   and
https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/412592/aria
so I wondered if there is a way that you can merge the two (if that is the way to go) ?

While I am not sure if what I have done is correct, I was able to write a function for $$
C_\theta(u, v)=\Phi_\theta\left(\Phi^{-1}(u), \Phi^{-1}(v)\right),
$$
pcopula.fam1 <- function(u, v, a) {
pbinorm(qnorm(u), qnorm(v), mean1 = 0, mean2 = 0, var1 = 1, var2 = 1, cov12=a)
}

This function works in R and has given me a value for my log-likelihood. Thank you for your help.

pbinorm is not a standard R function.  Where does it come from?  Regardless, assuming it performs the same calculation as I describe in my answer, your solution is identical to the one I posted.

@whuber Hello! the pbinorm is the cumulative distribution function for the bivariate normal distribution distribution and it is from the R package VGAM. Thank you for your help. Your code also gives me more or less the same answer.

Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your two accounts.
